# Selecting COUNT(id) and total in one SQL query

Tags: mysql

I have a load of items in a table. Each has a user_id.

I would like to find out the number of items per user as well as the total number of items.

If I do this:

```
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM items
GROUP BY user_id
```

...I get the number of items per user but I can't get the total number of items as they are grouped.

Is it possible to do this?

If so, is it a good way of doing things?

Would I be better of summing the counts after selecting them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following query will give you an additional row with the total number of items s and user_id=NULL.

```
SELECT user_id, COUNT(id) n_items
FROM items
GROUP BY user_id WITH ROLLUP
```

See also the [Mysql docs on GROUP BY modifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-modifiers.html).

Comment: It also took me one day of Googling and reading at the time to find out... I didn't know stackoveflow :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this...?

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM items
UNION
SELECT COUNT(id)
FROM items
GROUP BY user_id
```

Then the first result will be the total and the subsequent results will be the grouped totals.

But personally, I'd just add them up after doing the `group by` query as you said.